# Get part of string ( from sth -> to sth )

Tags: java, string

Hi
 I have a question about how to get only part of given string :

```
String = "1. Name:Tom\tNumber:123";
```

in this case I would like to get only part with name ( "Tom" )

Is there is any solution to do it?

Thank's for help

Comment: u can use substring method for this

Comment: Is this always the format it will be in?

Comment: Use regular expressions. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that format is how it always shows up this would work:

```
String str = "1. Name:Tom\tNumber:123";
String tom = str.substring(str.indexOf(':')+1, str.indexOf('\t'));
```

Using the first occurrence of `:` and the `\t` allows you to parse out the name. In the case of your `:`, you want to begin your string 1 character ahead.

Result:

> Tom

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple way assuming the format won't change.

```
int start = yourString.indexOf(':') + 1; //get character after this
int end = yourString.indexOf('\t');
String result = yourString.substring(start,end);
```

You can also write your own regex to match this.

Answer (score 0):

What you need, you will easyly find at the [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) documentation.